# What, if any, is a recommended way to structure similar 500,000 terms?

Tags: managed-metadata, term-store, term

I have a client that would like to use "tagging" to identify documents that are related to specific customer/case data.  Some terms would be customer identifiers with child terms for customer cases.  There are more than 1K customers so each customer cannot be its own term set and there are ~500K such cases.  It seems that within the managed metadata store limits (7 nested levels, 1,000 term sets, 30,000 terms per set, 1M max number of terms) we could come up with a hierarchy for these entities as terms.

Is this a valid way to structure managed metadata?

What are the repercussions of trying to use like terms across term sets?

Comment: How is logical architecture look like? I mean how many web applications, site collections, Mysites etc?

Comment: @FalakMahmood How is that relevant to the question?  


The managed metadata service is running in a service farm.  There are >1 content farms that use the shared MMS.  There is one web app with mysites (each person is of course its own site collection) but there will likely be 1 mysite webapp for each of the 12 global locations.  There are currently about 15 webapps running in SP 2007 & 2010 that will be migrated to realign with 3-4 2013 webapps.  Numerous site collections per web app.  All numbers are within the documented maximums.

Answer (score 1):

With that many terms, I think it would be better to use External Content Types, rather than MMS term sets. Have you considered that possibility?

For one thing, I'd imagine that the relevant data *is* in a database somewhere, given the volume of items. Using external content types also ensures you're not forced to maintain a large volume of metadata that probably changes frequently, plus you can keep the structure very close to how your business uses the information.

For example, I have an external content type defined to tag list items with a specific project from our project management system. All our projects are broken down into three levels: Project, phase, and task. I can simply add an external column to a list to look up a project, even down to the task level, and multiple columns of data can be displayed on the list for my selection. I don't have to maintain the metadata in SharePoint, because it's already maintained in the LOB application.